# CNN with Tensorflow, Keras | Accuracy not improving at all

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a deep learning model for multi-label image classification using Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN) in Python. Despite trying various combinations, the accuracy of my model only reaches up to 30%. Can anyone offer any suggestions on how to improve the accuracy of my model?

```
def baseline_model_1():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(1e-4,1e-4), input_shape=(height,weight,3)))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(1e-4,1e-4)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(1e-4,1e-4)))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(1e-4,1e-4)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=86, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(1e-4,1e-4)))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=86, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu", kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(1e-4,1e-4)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l1_l2(1e-4,1e-4)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

My image datagenerators looks like this

```
train_dataset = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    df_train,
    directory = directory_path_train,
    x_col = "image",
    y_col = "labels",
    target_size = (height, weight),
    class_mode = 'categorical',
    batch_size = bat_size,
    subset = "training",
    shuffle = True,
    seed = 1234,
    validate_filenames = False
)
validation_dataset = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    df_train,
    directory = directory_path_train,
    x_col = "image",
    y_col = "labels",
    target_size = (height, weight),
    class_mode='categorical',
    batch_size = bat_size,
    subset = "validation",
    shuffle = True,
    seed = 1234,
    validate_filenames = False
)
test_dataset = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    df_test,
    directory = directory_path_test,
    x_col = 'image',
    y_col = None,
    class_mode = None,
    target_size = (height, weight)
)
```

This is the output of it.

Found 14906 non-validated image filenames belonging to 6 classes.
Found 3726 non-validated image filenames belonging to 6 classes.
Found 3 validated image filenames.

Comment: Not exactly a fix for your problem, but it seems you are using the `ImageDataGenerator` class that `flow_from_dataframe` is a method of. You haven't said anything about the version of TensorFlow you are using, but the [current documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) marks this class as deprecated and provides suggestions on how to replace it. Maybe those are suitable for you.

Comment: I am using tensorflow 2.10 with python 3.9. However, after sometime my programs stops responding, so i just used cpu for training.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with "ADAM" optimizer? That won't be the issue, but it could improve the score. Also look into if the model is overfitting or not. If that's the case then lower your learning_rate. Also try using different batch_size. Also try with early stopping.

Comment: optimizer = ['SGD', 'RMSProp', 'Adagrad', 'Adamax', 'Adadelta', 'Nadam', 'Ftrl', 'adam']

Out of these, SGD gave an accuracy of around 30, rest kept it at 21 to 25.